# Boundedness condition in Theorem 5.3.2 of Evans

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

[image]

[image] Thanks!

I was going through this proof, and it mostly made sense to me. However, I don't understand where in the proof, boundedness of the open set $U$ is required. The construction of a smooth partition of unity does not require a bounded open cover, and the locally finite cover constructed [image]by Evans can also be applied to an unbounded open set $U$. Can someone explain where the proof fails?

Comment: It looks like this is not the whole proof, right?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz I have added the complete proof. My understanding after thinking about this for a bit is that if $U$ is unbounded, we cannot construct a compactly supported smooth partition of unity, thus not allowing us to obtain global convergence in the Sobolev norm. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

The original proof by Meyers and Serrin does not need boundedness.

https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/H-%3D-W.-Meyers-Serrin/e7a5f41b547afe5b8f38860436446a123c495738?utm_source=direct_link